# Цвет иконки отображается не тот, что нужно (xml)?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/circle_decorator" //#eeeeee
android:padding="8dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_print_dark"/>
```

Иконка имеет цвет #8B000000

Не понимаю, почему в приложении моя иконка светлее, чем ее заданный цвет?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тю, в котлине была прописана строка `setColorFilter(context.resources.getColor(R.color.ic_normal_dark))` , которая накладывалась маской на иконку.

В итоге прописал `setColorFilter(null)` и все стало на места